# How do i add a running total in A1 to B2 if there is a value OR subtract from C2 if there is a value

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

What I am trying to accomplish is that when I enter a number in B2 it will only subtract, 
A1-B2= A2 but if i put a number in C2 and nothing is in B2 I want it to add A1+C2=A2. I really tried looking for this problem everywhere. There were some similarities of some of the questions I have seen on Google and here but not exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. I know if it was in C# I would do something like this:

```
if(B2=="")
   A2= A1+C2;
if(C2=="")
   A2= A1-B2;
```

Not exact syntax but I hope it helps what what my question is. I would have posted an excel picture of my example but I apparently need a reputation of 10. I appreciate any help and thank you for your taking the time to read this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it will always be like either B2 or C2 are blank and both will never contain numbers at the same time, then you can simply use:

```
=A1+C2-B2
```

in cell A2.

Otherwise:

```
=IF(B2="",A1+C2,A1-B2)
```

Note that the above doesn't check C2 for blanks, so if both are blanks, you will get 0 in A2.

If you want to check *both* B2 and C2, then...

```
=IF(B2="",A1+C2,IF(C2="",A1-B2,"Both B2 and C2 are blanks")
```

And change the message as it suits you if both are blanks.

Comment: Really, I feel really dominated by excel right now. lol. I'm going to be using the first one because both will never contain numbers at the same time, really do appreciate that. @jerry

Comment: @Brandonl29 That's fine, and I felt like that too when I just started, and I'm sure there's so much more things in there that I will probably never need/use xP Feel free to mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: Would you mind voting up the question if you think its good enough. Thanks